# Ideal of Ring and Ring Polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to show that if 
$I \subset R$ is a maximal ideal that $I = R \cap F$ for some maximal ideal F of $R[X]$. Im trying to show that (I, X) is maximal in R[X] and that it thus follows.

I assume I can just show this by 
$$R[X] \rightarrow R/I $$
which sends $f(x)$ to $a_0 + I$. And this would induce an isomorphism which proves R[X]/(I,X) is a field.

Comment: You can try to show that $R[X]/(I,X) \cong R/I$ by sending a polynomial to its constant coefficient.

Comment: @M.Wang yes thank you I was thinking just that..

Comment: Hi! Im sorry, I'm new to ring theory and I have a question: how is $I = R \cap F$ defined? what confuses me is that $F$ is an ideal of polynomials over $R$, while $R$ is the ring itself

Comment: @FedePoncio We can see $R$ as a subring of $R[X]$. Then $I = R \cap F$ is the intersection of the subring $R$ and the maximal ideal $F$ taken inside $R[X]$.

Comment: @M.Wang Right! Thank you! Then if $(I,X)$ is maximal in $R[X]$, then $R[X]/(I,X)$ is a field, and if $R[X]/(I,X) \cong R/I$ by $f(x) \mapsto f(0)$, as you said, then $I$ must be maximal in $R$; right?

Comment: @FedePoncio That's right, OP is trying to show the inverse direction, i.e. $I$ maximal implies that $(I,X)$ is maximal. But since we have an isomorphism, $I$ is maximal iff $(I,X)$ is maximal.